# How do I get the index pairs from an inner join using pandas without creating the resulting dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to merge two dataframes, but instead of returning the full join just return two columns showing the paired rows.

I've written an example function below, but it creates the inner join of the two dataframes, including all columns that are not needed. If there are many columns and rows, this can use a lot of memory.

### example

```
def get_index_pairs(df1, df2, on):
     return pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on=on)[['index_x', 'index_y']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame( dict( key = ["a","b","c","d"], v1=[1,2,3,4]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame( dict( key = ["b","d","f","g"], v2=[10,20,30,40]))

pairs = get_index_pairs(df1, df2, on='key')

print(pairs)
```

### output

```
   index_x  index_y
0        1        0
1        3        1
```

I'm looking for a more memory efficient version of `get_index_pairs`.

Comment: The code from https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.4/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py might be a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution for Duplicate Keys (edited)

**Data**

The data is slightly adjusted for demo purpose. Specifically, `key="d"` will have a `2*2` Cartesian join.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame( dict( key = ["a","b","d","d"], v1=[1,2,3,4]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame( dict( key = ["b","d","d","g"], v2=[10,20,30,40]))
```

**Code**

Use `np.argwhere()` to return all matched indices.

```
ls = []
for i1, k1 in enumerate(df1["key"]):  # the only slow step (explicit for loop)
    for i2 in np.argwhere((df2["key"] == k1).values):
        ls.append([i1, i2[0]])

df_ans = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=["index_x", "index_y"])
```

**Result**

```
print(df_ans)

   index_x  index_y
0        1        0
1        2        1   <-  Cartesian join on "d" like what
2        2        2   <-  would be produced by an
3        3        1   <-  inner join
4        3        2   <-
```

**Note**

The OP asked for *reduced memory usage*, not faster execution. Otherwise `pd.merge()` would be preferred in terms of speed.

### Old Solution (no dup keys)

Construct `dict`s containing `{key: index}` pairs for your search. Only a constant multiple of the size of `dfN["key"]` would be consumed during the search process.

**Code**

```
# {key: index} mappings
dic1 = dict(zip(df1["key"].values, range(len(df1))))
dic2 = dict(zip(df2["key"].values, range(len(df2))))

# collect matched results
ls = []
for k1, v1 in dic1.items():  # the only slow step (explicit for loop)
    if k1 in dic2:  # fast (hashed search)
        ls.append([v1, dic2[k1]])

df_ans = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=["index_x", "index_y"])
```

**Result**

```
print(df_ans)

   index_x  index_y
0        1        0
1        3        1
```

Comment: This won't work if the keys are ever duplicated (which is allowed in a inner join)

Comment: Then `np.argwhere()` would get the job done. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use pandas DataFrame `align`, to align the axes bases on the `key`:

```
def get_index_pairs(df1, df2, on):
    left = pd.Series(df1.index, df1[on].array)
    right = pd.Series(df2.index, df2[on].array)
    left, right = left.align(right, join = 'inner')
    output = pd.DataFrame({'index_x':left, 'index_y':right})
    output.index = range(len(output))
    return output



df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(key=["a", "b", "c", "d"], v1=[1, 2, 3, 4]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(key=["b", "d", "f", "g"], v2=[10, 20, 30, 40]))

pairs = get_index_pairs(df1, df2, on="key")

print(pairs)

     index_x  index_y
0        1        0
1        3        1
```